# Translating SQL to MapReduce java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when trying to run the main class

Tags: java, hadoop, exception, mapreduce, nosuchmethod

i have 2 databases on text files: 
USERS(firstName, lastName, tel, zipCode, city)
CALLS(fromNumber, toNumber, duration)
i would like to translate this SQL request to MapReduce using Java

```
SELECT firstName, lastName
FROM users U, calls C
WHERE U.tel=C.toNumber AND U.City='Le Mans';
```

when i try to run my program on Hadoop cluster I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`, Help me please, this is my full code:

class UsersCallsJoin is the Program name
UsrTokenizerMapper is the Mapper of USERS file
CallsTokenizerMapper is the Mapper of CALLS file
UsersCallsReducer is the reducer

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class UsersCallsJoin {
    public static class UsrTokenizerMapper extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map (Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String record = value.toString();
            String[] parts = record.split(",");
            if (parts[4] == "LE MANS")
            context.write(new Text(parts[2]),new Text("usr\t" + parts[0]+":"+parts[1]));
        }

    }
    public static class CallsTokenizerMapper extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map (Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String record = value.toString();
            String[] parts = record.split(",");
            context.write(new Text(parts[1]), new Text("calls"));
        }
    }

        public static class UsersCallsReducer extends Reducer <Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String name = "";
        boolean callOK = false;
        boolean UsrOK = false;

        for (Text t : values) { 

        //String parts[] = t.toString().split("\t");
        if (t.toString().startsWith("usr")){
          UsrOK = true;
         parts = t.toString().split("\t");
         name = parts[1];
        }
        else if (t.toString().startsWith("calls")) 
        callOK = true;
        }

        if (UsrOK && callOK) {
            context.write(new Text(name), new Text(""));
        }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = new Job(conf, "user call");
            job.setJarByClass(UsersCallsJoin.class);
            job.setReducerClass(UsersCallsReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class, UsrTokenizerMapper.class);
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class, CallsTokenizerMapper.class);
            Path outputPath = new Path(args[2]);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
            outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
            }
        }
```

when I try to excuete it 
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar usercalljoin.jar UsersCallsJoin /path/to/users2.txt /path/to/calls2.txt output

This is the error that i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: UsersCallsJoin.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
```

Comment: Your main method is inside of the UsersCallsReducer inner class and not in the main (accidental pun) body of UsersCallJoin.  Move the main method out of the inner class and you should be good to go.

Comment: Solved by @JasonArmstrong, Thank You !

Comment: Why not use Hive or SparkSQL? In other words, writing actual MapReduce seems way too verbose to get the same data

Comment: Also, please do not use `==` for string comparison in Java